# PHP - regex parse template variable

Tags: php, regex

I have to parse this template string variable, for example:

```
$str = "<p>Don't want to receive email notifications? %%UNSUBSCRIBE['Adjust your message settings']%% values in your privacy.</p>";
```

My result should be this:

```
"<p>Don't want to receive email notifications? <a href='http://www.example.com/'>Adjust your message settings</a> values in your privacy.</p>"
```

How to do this in php/regex?

Comment: You should investigate a template engine like smarty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well heres a regex that matches that placeholder & captures 2 possible variables inside it which you might need:

`%%(UNSUBSCRIBE)\[\'(.*?)\'\]%%`

Something like `preg_replace("/%%(UNSUBSCRIBE)\[\'(.*?)\'\]%%/", "$1$2", $string)` should replace the whole placeholder with just the variables (the $1 and $2 represent the captured matches)...

Good luck!